# How to remove old data in redis when updating data?

Tags: redis, node-redis

I'm setting data in redis, but I update that data every minute, and I need redis to replace the old data with the new updated one. I am very confused as to how I might be able to achieve that. I tried to use client.expire('key', 60), but that doesn't seem to work. Below is my code. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
var redis = require("redis"),
client = redis.createClient();

const { promisify } = require("util");
const  setAsync = promisify(client.set).bind(client);

async function run(){

    //do something

    const success = await setAsync('mykey', list);
    console.log({success});
    client.expire('mykey', 59);  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the key will be deleted (or more precisely, marked for deletion) 59 seconds after calling `client.expire`, but there are 2 things you need to be aware of:

1. If you call the `EXPIRE` command on a key that already have a TTL, it'll **override** the pervious TTL.
2. The expiration timeout is cleared once the value of the key is overwritten (using `SET`, `DEL`, etc.).

BTW, in case you're updating the exact same key, the data will be overwritten anyway.. for example:

```js
await setAsync('key', 'value1'); // set 'key' to 'value1'
await setAsync('key', 'value2'); // override 'key' to 'value2'
await getAsync('key'); // 'value2'
```

Also, instead of running two commands, one for setting the value and one for setting the TTL, you can use the `EX` option like that:

```js
setAsync('key', 'value', 'EX', 60); // set `key` to `value` with TTL of 60 seconds
```